How to create multiple index fields in Amazon CloudSearch
Trying to create a Amazon CloudSearch domain and index fields.  I have manage to create the domain through AWS PHP SDK.  I want to create those index field through API SDK as well but I have many fields and I'm getting a rate exceeded error if I create a loop to create those field.
This is what I have so far
 $fields = [
        [
            'IndexFieldName' => 'field5',
            'IndexFieldType' => 'text',
        ],
        [
            'IndexFieldName' => 'field6',
            'IndexFieldType' => 'text',
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $this->client->defineIndexField([
            'DomainName' => $domain,
            'IndexField' => $field
        ]);
    }

This is actually working on my test environment and field5 and field6 were successfully created.  But on my actual production DB and mapping almost every field, I have to list all the fields and create those in AWS cloudsearch document.

try local secondary Indexes
   'LocalSecondaryIndexes' => array(
    array(
        'IndexName' => 'OrderDateIndex',
        'KeySchema' => array(
            array('AttributeName' => 'CustomerId', 'KeyType' => 'HASH'),
            array('AttributeName' => 'OrderDate',  'KeyType' => 'RANGE'),
        ),
        'Projection' => array(
            'ProjectionType' => 'KEYS_ONLY',
        ),
    ),
),

aws documentation like it
